# Sorting a list and dict keys

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I'm using python 2.7 and I have this list:

```
photos = ['arthur20.jpg', 'arthur7.jpg', 'arthur11.jpg', 'arthur3.jpg', 'arthur5.jpg', 'arthur17.jpg', 'arthur15.jpg', 'arthur2.jpg', 'arthur13.jpg', 'arthur8.jpg', 'arthur9.jpg', 'arthur18.jpg', 'arthur4.jpg', 'arthur6.jpg', 'arthur10.jpg', 'arthur12.jpg', 'arthur14.jpg', 'arthur19.jpg', 'arthur16.jpg', 'arthur1.jpg']
```

How I can organize this list? I tried to use `sort()` but it didn't work, it returned me this:

```
['arthur1.jpg', 'arthur10.jpg', 'arthur11.jpg', 'arthur12.jpg', 'arthur13.jpg', 'arthur14.jpg', 'arthur15.jpg', 'arthur16.jpg', 'arthur17.jpg', 'arthur18.jpg', 'arthur19.jpg', 'arthur2.jpg', 'arthur20.jpg', 'arthur3.jpg', 'arthur4.jpg', 'arthur5.jpg', 'arthur6.jpg', 'arthur7.jpg', 'arthur8.jpg', 'arthur9.jpg']
```

And also the strings of the list will be keys to a dict and I have to put the keys in order too, like this:

```
dict = {"arthur1.jpg":1, "arthur2.jpg":2 ...}
```

Comment: Although the accepted answer makes this clear implicitly - this question would benefit from an expansion of "it didn't work" - in what way did it not work?  A simplified input list and the order it was sorted to would clarify that and go some way to making a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Oh right, sorry I'll be more careful nextime. The reason it didn't is that when I dis use the sort() function to my "photos", the names would still not be in order: ["arthur10.jpg", "arthur8.jpg","arthur7.jpg", "arthur6.jpg","arthur5.jpg", "arthur20.jpg", arthur19.jpg", "arthur18.jpg", "arthur17.jpg" ...]. There would be segments in order in the list.

Comment: yeah - I understand the order you see is lexicographic - so you'll see e.g. ['arthur1','arthur10','arthur11','arthur2'...] after the sort.  The idea is here that you ask the question in a way that is clear for future readers and potential answerers - that's why I'm suggesting you edit otherwise the question is liable to be closed as it doesn't fulfil those criteria.  Check out [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for the official line on all this - I just picked up your question via the close vote review queue and thought I could offer a little advice.

Comment: ok thanks I'll be more careful and detailed nextime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sort()` would sort the list in its natural ordering, in this case - lexicographical ordering. You can sort it by the number following "arthur" with a custom sort function. The easiest way to do this, IMHO, would be to extract the number using a regular expression:

```
import re
photos.sort(key = lambda x : int(re.findall('\d+', x)[0]))
```

Once you have the list sorted, creating the `dict` you want is just a matter of `zip`ing:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dict = OrderedDict(zip(photos, range(1, len(photos) + 1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for the [`natsort`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/natsort) package which handles these more complicated sortings where the usual lexographic sorts will fail because the lengths of the numbers aren't normalized.

```
>>> natsorted(['arthur20.jpg', 'arthur7.jpg', 'arthur11.jpg', 
               'arthur3.jpg', 'arthur5.jpg', 'arthur17.jpg', 
               'arthur15.jpg', 'arthur2.jpg', 'arthur13.jpg',
               'arthur8.jpg', 'arthur9.jpg', 'arthur18.jpg', 
               'arthur4.jpg', 'arthur6.jpg', 'arthur10.jpg',
               'arthur12.jpg', 'arthur14.jpg', 'arthur19.jpg',
               'arthur16.jpg', 'arthur1.jpg'])
['arthur1.jpg', 'arthur2.jpg', 'arthur3.jpg', 'arthur4.jpg', 
 'arthur5.jpg', 'arthur6.jpg', 'arthur7.jpg', 'arthur8.jpg', 
 'arthur9.jpg', 'arthur10.jpg', 'arthur11.jpg', 'arthur12.jpg',     
 'arthur13.jpg', 'arthur14.jpg', 'arthur15.jpg', 'arthur16.jpg',
 'arthur17.jpg', 'arthur18.jpg', 'arthur19.jpg', 'arthur20.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import collections

origdict = {
        4: "four",
        5: "five",
        1: "one",
        2: "two"
    }
od = collections.OrderedDict()

for key in sorted(origdict.keys()):
    od[key] = origdict[key]

print od
```

Comment: This one is an understandable answer for beginners like me